# Creating filter rules java mail api

Tags: email, gmail, jakarta-mail

can anyone explain me how evolution manages email filtering referring this link [Evolution message filtering](https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=4468)

.How can i implement it in my email client application? thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty open ended question.  What part of the problem are you confused about?  JavaMail provides APIs to access all parts of a message.  You have to write the code to compare the message with the filter criteria you set up.  You might find the [java.mail.search](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/package-frame.html) package helpful.

Comment: My actual question is there any way that i create filter on mail client and those will also be applied on server like gmail?

Comment: There is no portable way to do that.  JavaMail won't help you.  Depending on your mail server, there may be a way to programmatically create mail filters that will be used on your server.  I don't know of a way to do that with Gmail.

Comment: @BillShannon So, I have to implement filters on client-side and apply those whenever i receive or send a mail?

Comment: Yes, that would be the portable way to do it.